# How to add datapoint to an alarm in aws cloudwatch in TargetTracking Scaling using the json file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

so I am using the TargetTracking Scaling to scale up my aws sagemaker endpoint by using two commands, which are:-

```
1. aws application-autoscaling register-scalable-target --service-namespace sagemaker --resource-id endpoint/{}/variant/AllTraffic --scalable-dimension sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount --min-capacity {} --max-capacity {}".format(endpoint_name,ENDPOINT_INSTANCE_MIN_COUNT,ENDPOINT_INSTANCE_MAX_COUNT))
```

"This command is used to register the endpoint to do the auto-scaling"

```
2.  aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy --policy-name myscalablepolicy --policy-type TargetTrackingScaling --resource-id endpoint/{}/variant/AllTraffic --service-namespace sagemaker --scalable-dimension sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount --target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration file://file.json".format(endpoint_name))
```

"This is used to actually add the target tracking scaling to aws sagemaker endpoint by taking the configuration from the file.json file"

Here is the content of my file.json file

```
{
  "TargetValue": 50,
  "CustomizedMetricSpecification": {
    "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
    "Namespace": "/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints",
    "Dimensions": [
      {
        "Name": "EndpointName",
        "Value": "debitscore-2019-12-17-10-26-16-605"
      },
      {
        "Name": "VariantName",
        "Value": "AllTraffic"
     }
    ],
    "Statistic": "Average"
  },
  "ScaleOutCooldown": 60,
  "ScaleInCooldown": 10,
  "DisableScaleIn": false
}
```

so it is working fine, but the issue is in AWS

1. Two-alarm has been configured after 2nd command runs, one is for high and second is for low, for reference see the image attached. And also how it is deciding to set the low alarm to 45 percent, I only mention for target value in the file.json file which is 50 in this case.

[image]

2. How to add the datapoint in alarm like in this it was taking 15 datapoints in 15 minutes and 3 datapoints in 3 minutes.

Comment: Edit and reattach your  image. It is not visible

Answer (score 0):

1. The high and low thresholds are based on the TargetValue in your target tracking scaling policy, and are determined by AWS when you put the scaling policy on the scalable target. The high and low thresholds are used to determine when you scale out and in your endpoint variant, respectively.
2. It looks like you are scaling based on CPUUtilization. The data points for that metric should be populated automatically by SageMaker for your endpoint. See CPUUtilization under "Processing Job, Training Job, Batch Transform Job, and Endpoint Instance Metrics" [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatch.html)